# Custom Taxonomy type in nav menu

Tags: custom-taxonomy

This might be a stupid question. But I really need the tip.

I've created several custom taxonomies in "post" type and everything is perfect. I can insert each custom term i create in the main nav menu. but what i'm looking for any way that if i could all the terms under a taxonomy in a menu item. That is if i click on a menu item say "Services" which is a custom taxonomy consists of terms such as "service 1, service 2 service 3" etc the page open will show all the posts which are under all the terms of this taxonomy. I can add each terms in the menu list but i don't want them to be different. And again I can create another parent term of all those terms and assign it in the nav menu but i don't want it either. But I don't want it to be so tricky. Please any idea from the experts. Thanks in advanced.

Comment: So you have a solution that works?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. my bad it wasn't working. I don't know why earlier it gave me the whole list of the posts underneath the taxonomy. Maybe another problem made it ;) but currently its only showing the 404 page :(